# 2003 Honda blinkers not working

Tags: troubleshooting

Okay I have a 2003 Honda crv and I was putting a new radio and had to splice a wire into the hazard switch all was fine but when I was putting the radio back in the wires pull apart so I took everything out and reconnected everything to what it was now my hazard lights will work but neither of my blinkers will does anyone have any ideas of what it could be

Comment: Seems like checking the fuses is the first step.  The turn signal and hazard light systems typically run off two diffferent fuses (so that hazard flashers can work with key off) even though they share the same bulbs.

Comment: Just curious, why did you splice into the hazard circuit during your radio install? That's not where you are pulling your constant 12v power, right?

Comment: As a car audio installer I'm very curious of why you spliced any wire with the hazard switch wire? You probably used it for constant 12v power or for the turn-on wire correct?

Comment: Sounds like you blew a fuse or either the radio is pulling too much power from the circuit that the signals run on preventing them from operating.